# Using for loop and other declared variables in ec2 userdata cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data, launch-configuration

I am new to cloudformation yaml.
I have the following which I need to use as userdata in launch configuration:

```
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub 
      - |
        #!/bin/bash -x
        apt-get -y update && apt install -y awscli mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev python-pip
          for item in certs user_prop config log
          do
            echo "... preparing ${item} database and config"
            MYSQL_DB_NAME="ext_as_${item}"
            LOCAL_DB_NAME=$(echo ${item}|tr -d '_')
            LOCAL_DB_FILE="/path/to/db/${LOCAL_DB_NAME}"
            DB_KEY="${item}_db"
            #- set db configuration value
            sed -i "s|${DB_KEY}=.*|${DB_KEY}==mysql://${DB_FQDN}/${MYSQL_DB_NAME}|" /path/to/config.conf
            #- create mysql db
            mysql --defaults-file=${MYSQL_PREF} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $${MYSQL_DB_NAME};"
            #- import local DB schema into MySql if no tables exist
            mysql --defaults-file=$${MYSQL_PREF} --silent --skip-column-names \
            -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '${MYSQL_DB_NAME}';"|grep -e ^0 -q \
            && ./dbcvt -t ${item} -s sqlite:///${LOCAL_DB_FILE} -d mysql://${DB_FQDN}/${MYSQL_DB_NAME} -p ${MYSQL_PREF}
          done
        popd
      - 
        DB_FQDN:
          'Fn::ImportValue': 'OVPNConfigDbEndpoint'
```

Now the problem is `DB_FQDN` gets resolved but `LOCAL_DB_FILE`, `LOCAL_DB_NAME`, `DB_KEY`, `MYSQL_DB_NAME`, and `MYSQL_PREF` don't get resolved. Now the questions are:

1. If I hard-code the other values, how do I use a for loop in a userdata shell script ?
2. Do I have to always use a Fn::Join as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535452/4035062 by Alex ?
   using `Fn::Join` to write a simple shell script seems quite complicated.
3. What does `+` mean in `!Sub |+` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have there is that you want the variables like `${item}` to be expanded inside the Bash Shell whereas the `Fn::Sub` Cloudformation intrinsic function also interprets `${item}` as a variable to expand.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (`${}`) literally, add an exclamation point (`!`) after the open curly brace, such as `${!Literal}`. AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as `${Literal}`.

Keep in mind, however, that the braces in Bash are usually optional. That is to say, you can usually rewrite `${item}` simply as `$item`.

A quick look at your code suggests to me that you can rewrite it like this and it should be fine:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub 
   - |
     #!/bin/bash -x
     apt-get -y update && apt install -y awscli mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev python-pip
     for item in certs user_prop config log
     do
       echo "... preparing $item database and config"
       MYSQL_DB_NAME="ext_as_$item"
       LOCAL_DB_NAME=$(echo $item | tr -d '_')
       LOCAL_DB_FILE="/path/to/db/$LOCAL_DB_NAME"
       DB_KEY="${!item}_db"
       #- set db configuration value
       sed -i "s|$DB_KEY=.*|$DB_KEY==mysql://${DB_FQDN}/$MYSQL_DB_NAME|" /path/to/config.conf
       #- create mysql db
       mysql --defaults-file=$MYSQL_PREF -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $MYSQL_DB_NAME;"
       #- import local DB schema into MySql if no tables exist
       mysql --defaults-file=$MYSQL_PREF --silent --skip-column-names \
       -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$MYSQL_DB_NAME';"|grep -e ^0 -q \
       && ./dbcvt -t $item -s sqlite:///$LOCAL_DB_FILE -d mysql://${DB_FQDN}/$MYSQL_DB_NAME -p $MYSQL_PREF
     done
     popd
   - 
     DB_FQDN:
       'Fn::ImportValue': 'OVPNConfigDbEndpoint'
```

Points to note well:

- See that on the `DB_KEY` the `${!item}` notation is required, because Bash would otherwise expand the variable `${item_db}` without the braces there.
- In the case of `${DB_FQDN}` you of course need to use `${DB_FQDN}` because in that case you do want the substitution by `Fb::Sub`.
- Note also that I fixed some typos in your Bash. You had `$$` as a typo in 2 places.

To your other questions:

- No you don't need to use `Fn::Join`. That question you were looking at was about if someone for some reason did want to interpolate `Fn::Join`. That answer shows one way you can do that.
- The notation `|+` is a feature of the YAML language. It just says to keep the newlines after the block. See this YAML [cheatsheet](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/YAML).

Comment: Hi @Alex. great explanation. Thanks a lot for this. Actually there are a lot of tricks in cloudformation. e.g. ${!variable} in bash has an entire different meaning than ${!variable} in cloudformation, din't know that.